# Jolt transformation for grouping and counting array

Tags: json, jolt

What is the Jolt Spec to count and index a list of files by directories?

**Input JSON:**

```json
[
  {
    "path": "/test/2007-07-02",
    "filename": "datafile_00001.parquet"
  },
  {
    "path": "/test/2007-07-03",
    "filename": "datafile_00005.parquet"
  },
  {
    "path": "/test/2007-07-03",
    "filename": "datafile_00014.parquet"
  }
]
```

JOLT Transformation:

1. Match any value of path, go up the tree 3 levels,  grab the whole array element, and write it to the output in an array
2. Group the data
3. Convert from a map to a top-level list
4. Count "files"

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "path": {
          "*": { 
            "@(3,[&2])": "&.[]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "&.path",
        "*": {
          "filename": "&2.files[]"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "[#1]"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "cnt": "=size(@(1,files))"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Expected Output:**

```json
[
  {
    "path": "/test/2007-07-02",
    "filename": "datafile_00001.parquet",
    "id": 1,
    "cnt": 1
  },
  {
    "path": "/test/2007-07-03",
    "filename": "datafile_00005.parquet",
    "id": 1,
    "cnt": 2
  },
  {
    "path": "/test/2007-07-03",
    "filename": "datafile_00014.parquet",
    "id": 2,
    "cnt": 2
  }
]
```

**Current Output:**

```json
[
  {
    "path": "/test/2007-07-02",
    "files": [
      "datafile_00001.parquet"
    ],
    "cnt": 1
  },
  {
    "path": "/test/2007-07-03",
    "files": [
      "datafile_00005.parquet",
      "datafile_00014.parquet"
    ],
    "cnt": 2
  }
]
```

Please help me to add the order number and count keys to the existing ones. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

- Group by **`path`** attribute while converting them to arrays through
  use of **`"@(1,path).&[]"`** on the right-hand-side in order to be able to use ***size*** function.

Then

- Use **$** wildcard and ***intSum*** function in order to increment
  object keys by one to determine **`id`** values

such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "@(1,path).&[]"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "cnt": "=size(@(1,filename))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2.&.&1"
        },
        "cnt": "&1.&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2.&1.&",
          "$": "&2.&1.id",
          "@1,cnt": "&2.&1.cnt"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "cnt": ""
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "id": "=intSum(@(1,&),1)"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what is `id` in your problem! So I want to ignore it and use the index of the array as your id.

So you can use like below example:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[&1].&",
        "$": "[&1].id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "path": {
          "@(2,[&1])": "@(1).[]"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "cnt": "=size(@(2))",
          "id": "=toInteger"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you! Id is order number in a group