# How to count the number of records of a JSON object using JOLT

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

Using this json file, it is required to create a summary by station wise.

**Input JSON:**

```json
[
  {
    "time": "2024-03-25T00:00:00Z",
    "station": "1",
    "temp": "2.0",
    "rain": "1.6"
  },
  {
    "time": "2024-03-25T01:00:00Z",
    "station": "1",
    "temp": "2.6",
    "rain": "2.1"
  },
  {
    "time": "2024-03-25T01:00:00Z",
    "station": "2",
    "temp": "2.6",
    "rain": "2.1"
  },
  {
    "time": "2024-03-25T01:00:00Z",
    "station": "3",
    "temp": "2.6",
    "rain": "2.1"
  }
]
```

**Desired output:**

```json
[
  {
    "sid": "1",
    "cnt": 2
  },
  {
    "sid": "2",
    "cnt": 1
  },
  {
    "sid": "3",
    "cnt": 1
  }
]
```

How we can do this with JOLT ?

I have used this code from [Jolt transformation for grouping and counting array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75608100/jolt-transformation-for-grouping-and-counting-array).

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "station": {
          "@(2,[&1])": "@(1).[]"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "cnt": "=size(@(2))",
          "id": "=toInteger"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But it is giving me the output as follows which is not as expected.

```json
[
  {
    "time": "2024-03-25T00:00:00Z",
    "station": "1",
    "temp": "2.0",
    "rain": "1.6",
    "cnt": 2
  },
  {
    "time": "2024-03-25T01:00:00Z",
    "station": "1",
    "temp": "2.6",
    "rain": "2.1",
    "cnt": 2
  },
  {
    "time": "2024-03-25T01:00:00Z",
    "station": "2",
    "temp": "2.6",
    "rain": "2.1",
    "cnt": 1
  },
  {
    "time": "2024-03-25T01:00:00Z",
    "station": "3",
    "temp": "2.6",
    "rain": "2.1",
    "cnt": 1
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group the objects by the values of `station` such as

```json
[
  { // make station values object keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "station": "@1,station.&"
      }
    }
  },
  { // count the occurence of each station through use of size function
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "cnt": "=size(@(1,station))"
      }
    }
  },
  { // pick only one station value among repeating same values
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "ONE"
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the object keys while wrapping the whole JSON with square brackets
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[#2].&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the **demo** on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: Nice to help @casper , kindly you can upvote and mark as well, thanks in advance.